# Query methods in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

How can I make query from function VisitService to get date method "from" "to" and show in my html page.
Is this code will work good ??

Is better with explainition

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('projectsEvaluationApp')
    .factory('EvaluationsService', EvaluationsService)
    .factory('VisitService', VisitService)
    .factory('WebPagesService', WebPagesService);

EvaluationsService.$inject = ['$resource'];
VisitService.$inject = ['$resource'];
WebPagesService.$inject = ['$resource'];

function EvaluationsService ($resource) {
    var service = $resource('api/evaluations/:id', {}, {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        },
        'query': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
        }
    });

    return service;
}

function VisitService ($resource) {
    var service = $resource('api/visits/:id', {}, {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        },
        'query': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
        }
    });

    return service;
}
function WebPagesService ($resource) {
    var service = $resource('api/web-pages/:id', {}, {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        },
        'query': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
        }
    });

    return service;
}

})();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of to use $resource you need to install and inject ng-resource
You can use like this

```
function VisitService ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/visits/:id', {}, {
    }).query();
}
```

Default query method is GET with default isArray as true

If you want to pass a query parameter
Your API will be

```
function VisitService (fromDate,toDate) {
            return $resource(''api/visits?fromDater' + fromDate + '&toDate' + toDate', {}, {
            }).query();

}
```

Call it in controller

```
$scope.test = VisitService('01/04/2016','01/04/2016');
```

User in HTML

```
{{test}}
```